# How to properly reference a Table from an inactive Sheet for RowSource property in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill a `ListBox` in a `Userform` through the `RowSource` property and a `Table` object containing the information in an inactive `Sheet` named `Data`, using Excel VBA. My code mostly works, but has a serious flaw: it only works when the `Sheet` containing the `Table` with the data is active (selected between all the sheets in the workbook).

The code I tried is the following:

```
ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets("Data").Range("Table 1[[Column1]:[Column4]]").Address(0, 0)
```

The issue is that the range returned doesn't refer to any `Sheet`, it simply is something like `B2:E5` which just adds blank rows to `ListBox1`. The range returned by the code should be something like `Data!B2:E5`. My problem is that I can't just hard code this. For the sample code I simplified the reference, but the `Table` chose to get the data from will vary (all these tables are on the same `Sheet`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Address` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144076);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) has several other parameters.  You need to include the External parameter

```
.Address(0, 0, ,1)
```

ie

```
ListBox1.RowSource = Worksheets("Data").Range("Table1[[Column1]:[Column4]]").Address(0, 0, ,1)
```

Explanation:

1. `Worksheets("Data").Range("Table1[[Column1]:[Column4]]")` correctly return a range reference to the `Data` sheet.  The `.Address(0, 0)` returns just the Row/Column part of that address (eg as you say `B2:E5`)
2. When you write `B2:E5` to the `RowSourse` property, that tells the ListBox to get the data from that address *on the ActiveSheet*
3. `Address(0, 0, ,1)` returns a fully qualified reference, including the Workbook and Worksheet

Comment: I wasn''t aware of this possibility but it does exactly what I need. Thank you very much for your help!